Filtering Programmatically on sfDataGrid Loading
I need to apply a UI filter to my strStatus Column for my sfDataGrid, as soon as it loads, then the user must be able to do their own UI filtering later on, by devault i want to filter to everything where strStatus != "Delivered", but later on I still want them to be able to tick Delivered, to view the Delivered orders.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:isendoff/controllers/authController.dart';
import 'package:isendoff/controllers/dashboardController.dart';
import 'package:isendoff/shared/colors.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/datepicker.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:isendoff/shared/spacing.dart';

class DashboardPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final DashboardController dashboardController =
      Get.put(DashboardController());
  final AuthController authController = Get.put(AuthController());
  final DataGridController dtOrdersController = DataGridController();
  final RxBool expandDateRange = false.obs;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    fetchData();
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: null,
          title:
              Obx(() => Text('Welcome ${dashboardController.userName.value}')),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
              onPressed: fetchData,
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
              onPressed: () {
                authController.logout();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: listDateSelector(),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: dtOrders(),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final selectedRows = dtOrdersController.selectedRows;
                final lines =
                    RxList<Orders>.from(dashboardController.sendOffLines);

                if (selectedRows.isNotEmpty) {
                  for (var row in selectedRows) {
                    final order = Orders(
                      bitChecked: row.getCells()[0].value,
                      strCustName: row.getCells()[1].value.toString(),
                      strCustDesc: row.getCells()[2].value.toString(),
                      strLocation: row.getCells()[3].value.toString(),
                      strDeliveryMethod: row.getCells()[4].value.toString(),
                      strRef: row.getCells()[5].value.toString(),
                      strOrderDoc: row.getCells()[6].value.toString(),
                      strInvDocID: row.getCells()[7].value.toString(),
                      strStatus: row.getCells()[8].value.toString(),
                      dteRequiredDate: row.getCells()[9].value.toString(),
                      intUnitTypeOne: row.getCells()[10].value,
                      intUnitTypeTwo: row.getCells()[11].value,
                      intUnitTypeThree: row.getCells()[12].value,
                      intUnitTypeFour: row.getCells()[13].value,
                      intUnitTypeFive: row.getCells()[14].value,
                      intCreatedBy: row.getCells()[15].value,
                      strCreatedBy: row.getCells()[16].value.toString(),
                      strReceivedBy: row.getCells()[17].value.toString(),
                      imgSignature: row.getCells()[18].value.toString(),
                      dtmCreated: row.getCells()[19].value.toString(),
                      strNotes: row.getCells()[20].value.toString(),
                    );
                    lines.add(order);
                  }
                  dashboardController.sendOffLines = RxList<Orders>.from(lines);
                }
                ;
                for (Orders order in dashboardController.sendOffLines) {
                  print(order.strOrderDoc);
                }

                Get.toNamed('/submit');
              },
              child: Text('SEND OFF'),
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }

  void fetchData() {
    dashboardController.fetchLoadedOrders(
        dashboardController.startDate.value, dashboardController.endDate.value);
    dashboardController.loadUsername();
  }

  filterData() {
    dtOrdersController
        .filterRows((row) => row.cells['strStatus'].value != 'Delivered');
  }

  // Date Range on change event to get data
  void updateDataRange(DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs args) {
    if (args.value is PickerDateRange) {
      if (args.value.endDate != null) {
        String startDateStr =
            DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(args.value.startDate);
        String endDateStr = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
            .format(args.value.endDate ?? args.value.startDate);
        dashboardController.startDate.value = DateTime.parse(startDateStr);
        dashboardController.endDate.value = DateTime.parse(endDateStr);
        dashboardController.fetchLoadedOrders(
            dashboardController.startDate.value,
            dashboardController.endDate.value);
      }
    }
  }

  // Date Range visibility
  void toggleExpansion() {
    expandDateRange.value = !expandDateRange.value;
  }

  Widget listDateSelector() {
    return Obx(() {
      return Column(
        children: [
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
            title: Text('Date Range Picker',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            onTap: () => toggleExpansion(),
          ),
          if (expandDateRange.value)
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(CSizes.padMD),
              child: SfDateRangePicker(
                onSelectionChanged: updateDataRange,
                selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.range,
                initialSelectedRange: PickerDateRange(
                  dashboardController.startDate.value,
                  dashboardController.endDate.value,
                ),
                selectionTextStyle: TextStyle(color: CColors.dark4),
                rangeTextStyle: TextStyle(color: CColors.dark4),
                startRangeSelectionColor: CColors.app3,
                rangeSelectionColor: CColors.app2,
                endRangeSelectionColor: CColors.app3,
                todayHighlightColor: CColors.app1,
              ),
            ),
        ],
      );
    });
  }

  Widget dtOrders() {
    return Obx(() {
      // Define your data table here
      return SfDataGrid(
        source: OrdersDataSource(orders: dashboardController.loadedOrders),
        columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.auto,
        allowFiltering: true,
        selectionMode: SelectionMode.multiple,
        showCheckboxColumn: true,
        columns: [
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'bitChecked',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'Checked',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'strCustName',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'Customer Name',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'strCustDesc',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'Customer Description',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'strLocation',
            visible: false,
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'Location',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'strDeliveryMethod',
            visible: false,
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'Delivery Method',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'strRef',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'Customer Order No.',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'strOrderDoc',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'SO Number',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'strInvDocID',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'Invoice Number',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'strStatus',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'Status',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'dteRequiredDate',
            visible: false,
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'Date Required',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'intUnitTypeOne',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'Cartons',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'intUnitTypeTwo',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'Boxes',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'intUnitTypeThree',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'Pairs/Units',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'intUnitTypeFour',
            visible: false,
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'TBC',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'intUnitTypeFive',
            visible: false,
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'TBC',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'intCreatedBy',
            visible: false,
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'User ID',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'strCreatedBy',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'Logged By',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'strReceivedBy',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'Recieved By',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'imgSignature',
            label: const SizedBox.shrink(),
            width: 100,
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'dtmCreated',
            visible: false,
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'Date Time',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridColumn(
            columnName: 'strNotes',
            label: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'Notes',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        onSelectionChanged: (addedRows, removedRows) {
          if (addedRows.isNotEmpty) {
            var selectedIndex = dtOrdersController.selectedIndex;
            String selectedCustomerName = addedRows.last.getCells()[1].value;

            if (dtOrdersController.selectedRows.isNotEmpty) {
              String previousCustomerName =
                  dtOrdersController.selectedRows.first.getCells()[1].value;

              if (previousCustomerName != selectedCustomerName) {
                // print('Selected customer: $selectedCustomerName');
                dtOrdersController.selectedIndex = -1;
                dtOrdersController.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
              }
            }
          }
        },
        controller: dtOrdersController,
      );
    });
  }
}

class OrdersDataSource extends DataGridSource {
  OrdersDataSource({
    required RxList<Orders> orders,
  }) {
    dataGridRows = orders.map<DataGridRow>((dataGridRow) {
      // Decode base64 image
      Image? signatureImage;
      if (dataGridRow.imgSignature.isNotEmpty) {
        final bytes = base64Decode(dataGridRow.imgSignature);
        signatureImage = Image.memory(
          bytes,
          width: 50, // Adjust width as needed
          height: 50, // Adjust height as needed
          fit: BoxFit.cover, // Adjust fit as needed
        );
      } else {
        signatureImage = null; // No image available
      }

      return DataGridRow(
        cells: [
          DataGridCell<int>(
            columnName: 'bitChecked',
            value: dataGridRow.bitChecked,
          ),
          DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'strCustName',
            value: dataGridRow.strCustName,
          ),
          DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'strCustDesc',
            value: dataGridRow.strCustDesc,
          ),
          DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'strLocation',
            value: dataGridRow.strLocation,
          ),
          DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'strDeliveryMethod',
            value: dataGridRow.strDeliveryMethod,
          ),
          DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'strRef',
            value: dataGridRow.strRef,
          ),
          DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'strOrderDoc',
            value: dataGridRow.strOrderDoc,
          ),
          DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'strInvDocID',
            value: dataGridRow.strInvDocID,
          ),
          DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'strStatus',
            value: dataGridRow.strStatus,
          ),
          DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'dteRequiredDate',
            value: dataGridRow.dteRequiredDate,
          ),
          DataGridCell<int>(
            columnName: 'intUnitTypeOne',
            value: dataGridRow.intUnitTypeOne,
          ),
          DataGridCell<int>(
            columnName: 'intUnitTypeTwo',
            value: dataGridRow.intUnitTypeTwo,
          ),
          DataGridCell<int>(
            columnName: 'intUnitTypeThree',
            value: dataGridRow.intUnitTypeThree,
          ),
          DataGridCell<int>(
            columnName: 'intUnitTypeFour',
            value: dataGridRow.intUnitTypeFour,
          ),
          DataGridCell<int>(
            columnName: 'intUnitTypeFive',
            value: dataGridRow.intUnitTypeFive,
          ),
          DataGridCell<int>(
            columnName: 'intCreatedBy',
            value: dataGridRow.intCreatedBy,
          ),
          DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'strCreatedBy',
            value: dataGridRow.strCreatedBy,
          ),
          DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'strReceivedBy',
            value: dataGridRow.strReceivedBy,
          ),
          DataGridCell<Image?>(
            columnName: 'imgSignature',
            value: signatureImage,
          ), // Use nullable Image type),
          DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'dtmCreated',
            value: dataGridRow.dtmCreated,
          ),
          DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'strNotes',
            value: dataGridRow.strNotes,
          ),
        ],
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  List<DataGridRow> dataGridRows = [];

  @override
  List<DataGridRow> get rows => dataGridRows;

  @override
  DataGridRowAdapter? buildRow(DataGridRow row) {
    return DataGridRowAdapter(
      cells: row.getCells().map<Widget>((dataGridCell) {
        if (dataGridCell.columnName == 'imgSignature') {
          // Display image widget
          final Image? signatureImage = dataGridCell.value as Image?;
          return Container(
            // color: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
            child: signatureImage ??
                null, // Display placeholder if no image available
          );
        } else if (dataGridCell.columnName == 'bitChecked') {
          final int? bitChecked = dataGridCell.value as int?;
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: bitChecked == 1 ? Icon(Icons.check) : Icon(Icons.close),
          );
        } else if (dataGridCell.columnName == 'intUnitTypeOne' ||
            dataGridCell.columnName == 'intUnitTypeTwo' ||
            dataGridCell.columnName == 'intUnitTypeThree' ||
            dataGridCell.columnName == 'intUnitTypeFour' ||
            dataGridCell.columnName == 'intUnitTypeFive') {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              dataGridCell.value.toString(),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: CSizes.padMD),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              dataGridCell.value.toString(),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          );
        }
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}


I cant seem to find any built in function for sfDataGrids that allows you to apply a filter on load

To apply filtering during the initial loading, the DataSource.addFilter() method can be used. In fetchData(), after fetching the necessary data, the programmatic filtering can be applied to the rows based on the specified condition. However, based on the sample, it seems that the OrdersDataSource directly in the DataGrid. This implies that whenever the DataGrid is rebuild, the source is newly initialized. The OrdersDataSource object is intended to be long-lived and not recreated with each build, which might impact the DataGrid's behavior.
To avoid this issue, maintain OrdersDataSource as a common instance and initialize it only after fetching the required data. By following this approach, the filter can be applied to the rows during the initial loading. Please refer to the following code snippet for more information.
 late EmployeeDataSource employeeDataSource;

 List<_Product> productlist = [];

 

void fetchData() {

   // Put your required logic to fetch data.

 

   // Replace with your DataSource.

   // After fetching the data, you can initialize the DataSource.

   employeeDataSource = EmployeeDataSource(productlist);

   // Apply programmatic filtering on your specified condition.

   employeeDataSource.addFilter('customerID',

       const FilterCondition(type: FilterType.notEqual, value: 'ALFKI'));

 }

